# Running a conditional script in bash

Tags: bash

This is the code I'm using to check the current git branch,

```
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
```

I want to run the following code conditionally if the branch is master

```
cd build && aws s3 cp . s3://www.examle.com/ --recursive
```

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: As in most languages you would use an `if` statement. Look them up in your favorite [bash language reference](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)

Comment: BTW, I'd maybe make it `(cd build && exec aws s3 ...)` -- adding the `exec` balances out the performance impact of the subshell created by the parens (by consuming it), while scoping the `cd` to only change the directory where that one `aws s3` command is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')
if [ "$branch" = master ]; then
   cd build && aws s3 cp . s3://www.examle.com/ --recursive
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like below

```
[[ "$branch" == master ]] && cd build && aws s3 cp . s3://www.examle.com/ --recursive
```